# Facing an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Tags: javascript, json, list

I am building a ToDo List but facing an error

```
VM619:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at showNotes (javapractice.html:121)
    at javapractice.html:97
showNotes @ javapractice.html:121
(anonymous) @ javapractice.html:97
```

This is how my code looks
[Javascript Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeI8c.png)

In continuation to above, I want the delete button to work and hence wrote the below code.

```
 else {
            notesElm.innerHTML = `Nothing to show fucker`;
        }
    }
    // function to delete note
    function deleteNote(index) {
        console.log("Deleteme", index);

        let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
        if (notes == null) {
            notesObj = [];
        } else {
            notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
        }

        notesObj.splice(index, 1);
        localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
        showNotes();
```

But the button is not working.

Entire code

```
<script>

    console.log('Welcome to Notes app');
    showNotes();

    let addBtn = document.getElementById("addBtn");
    addBtn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {

        let addTxt = document.getElementById("addTxt");
        let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
        if (notes == null) {
            notesObj = [];
        } else {
            notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
        }
        notesObj.push(addTxt.value);
        localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
        addTxt.value = "";
        //console.log(notesObj);
        showNotes();
    });

    function showNotes() {
        let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
        if (notes == null) {
            notesObj = [];
        } else {
            notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
        }
        let html = "";
        notesObj.forEach(function (element, index) {
            html += `
                <div class= "notecard my-2 mx-2 card" style="width: 18rem;" >
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Note ${index + 1} </h5>
                    <p class="card-text"> ${element + 1}</p>
                    <button id="${index}" onclock="deleteNote(this.id)" class="btn btn-primary">Delete Note</button>
                </div>
        </div> `
        });
        let notesElm = document.getElementById("notes");
        if (notesObj.length != 0) {
            notesElm.innerHTML = html;
        }
        else {
            notesElm.innerHTML = `Nothing to show fucker`;
        }
    }
    // function to delete note
    function deleteNote(index) {
        console.log("Deleteme", index);

        let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
        if (notes == null) {
            notesObj = [];
        } else {
            notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
        }

        notesObj.splice(index, 1);
        localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
        showNotes();
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Please post you code as text, not an image of text.

Comment: What is the JSON this code is trying to parse?

Comment: Please add to a post screenshot of `console.log(notesObject)` output. Place it right after 109 line

Comment: @ScottHunter I posted the code in text but it doesn't show the line number. Thats why I had to add it as an image.

Comment: @AidOnline01 I didn't get you.

Comment: @RishabhGupta, you should get us more info. In particular I need to see what is content of notesObject you are trying to json encode. Please write `console.log(notesObject)` and attach screenshot of console output

Comment: @AidOnline01 Thanks for your input. The code is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first line of `showNotes` function (line 117 on your screen shot), `let Notes = …` "Notes" should have a lower "n"

Comment: That helped remove the error. But now I am getting another error.                                                                                                                                          Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementbyId is not a function
    at showNotes (javapractice.html:134)
    at javapractice.html:97

Comment: because it is `document.getElementById` with an upper "B"

Comment: I am unable to make the delete button work. Please check the updated question for the written code.

Comment: Do you correctly see "Deleteme …" in the console? Do you have any error message?

Comment: No error message in console.

Comment: what about 'Deleteme …' (from your `deleteNote` function) do you see that in the console ?

Comment: When I type deleteNote in the console. This comes up ``` function deleteNote(index) {
        console.log("Deleteme", index);

        let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
        if (notes == null) {
            notesObj = [];
        } else {
            notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
        }

        notesObj.splice(index, 1);
        localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
        showNotes();
    } = $2.  ```

Comment: What I meant is, in your code you have `console.log("Deleteme", index);` do you see that being printed out in the console ?

Comment: The only thing which appears in console is "Welcome to Notes app" "javapractice.html:96" which points to "console.log('Welcome to Notes app');"

Comment: This means the `deleteNote` is never called

Comment: Yes. I also commented out the  "console.log('Welcome to Notes app')" thinking it might be the reason for deleteNote not being called out but despite that the error remains the same. What can I do?

Comment: "the error remains" but you don't have any error message right ? simply you don't get the expected result, correct ? Can you post the entire code or at least the relevent part where we could replicate the problem

Comment: Yes. Yes. Please check above for the entire code.

Comment: there is a typo in this line `<button id="${index}" onclock="deleteNote(this.id)" class="btn btn-primary">Delete Note</button>` it should be `onclick` with a "i" and not a "o".

Comment: Thanks man! Appreciate it.